# General recommendations and tricks of how to instantiate fields and call methods

Tags: string, for-loop, javafx

I want to instantiate a large number of StringProperty fields to put text values
(>100000). All in all my code performs well so far. I'm still trying to optimize my code as well as possible to harness the full power capabilities of my weak CPU (Intel Atom N2600, 1,6GHz, 2GByte Ram).

I'm calling the following method 100000 times and it takes some seconds
until all values are stored in my array of StringProperty.

```
public setData(int row, int numberOfCols, String data [][]) {
        this.dataValue = new StringProperty[numberOfCols];
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfCols;i++) dataValue[i] = new SimpleStringProperty(data[row][i]);
}
```

Is the method above good enough for intantiating fields and putting values?
Any alternative ideas of how to tweak the method above?

Comment: Do you really need over a million string properties? To what purpose?

Comment: jewelsea not really, but a data set with 100000 entries is a realistic entry of values. I changed the value to 100000

Comment: [Profiling](https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html) is a good way to analyze performance.

Comment: @jewelsea - sadly, VisualVM fails to profile JavaFX applications. There are other options, but only proprietary ones AFAIK.

Comment: Consider using `ObservableList<String>` instead of that many properties...